# How do I use a custom layout for a carousel item in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, layout

I am using this library to put a carousel view in an Android app: https://github.com/ImaginativeShohag/Why-Not-Image-Carousel

I'm also trying to use the showcase type, but a prerequisite to use this type is creating a custom layout for the carousel items.

[image]

Creating the layout I understand, but the OP uses this example in Kotlin to show how the custom layout is actually used:

```
binding.carousel3.carouselListener = object : CarouselListener {
                override fun onCreateViewHolder(
                    layoutInflater: LayoutInflater,
                    parent: ViewGroup
                ): ViewBinding? {
                    return ItemCustomFixedSizeLayout1Binding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
                }

                override fun onBindViewHolder(
                    binding: ViewBinding,
                    item: CarouselItem,
                    position: Int
                ) {
                    val currentBinding = binding as ItemCustomFixedSizeLayout1Binding

                    currentBinding.imageView.apply {
                        scaleType = imageScaleType

                        // carousel_default_placeholder is the default placeholder comes with
                        // the library.
                        setImage(item, R.drawable.carousel_default_placeholder)
                    }
                }
            }

            val listThree = mutableListOf<CarouselItem>()

            for (item in DataSet.three) {
                listThree.add(
                    CarouselItem(
                        imageUrl = item.first,
                        caption = item.second
                    )
                )
            }

            binding.carousel3.setData(listThree)

            binding.customCaption.isSelected = true

            binding.carousel3.onScrollListener = object : CarouselOnScrollListener {

                override fun onScrollStateChanged(
                    recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                    newState: Int,
                    position: Int,
                    carouselItem: CarouselItem?
                ) {
                    if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                        carouselItem?.apply {
                            binding.customCaption.text = caption
                        }
                    }
                }

                override fun onScrolled(
                    recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                    dx: Int,
                    dy: Int,
                    position: Int,
                    carouselItem: CarouselItem?
                ) {
                    // ...
                }
            }

            // Custom navigation
            binding.btnGotoPrevious.setOnClickListener {
                binding.carousel3.previous()
            }

            binding.btnGotoNext.setOnClickListener {
                binding.carousel3.next()
            }
```

I'm having some trouble figuring out what exactly this code is doing and how it would look in Java. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**A Quick Guess**

It seems that the listener is providing the callback of Recycler View. If you need me to guess within a second, and I will say the custom view is a Recycler View using listener to allow users to register the Recycler View methods (which is the Adapter using in the RV)

---

**Deep Investigation**

**1st question:** What is the Custom View class for id=carousel3 in KotlinActivity in the sample project

**Ans:** `org.imaginativeworld.whynotimagecarousel.ImageCarousel`.

(P.S. identical between activity_kotlin.xml and activity_test.xml)

(Below is a screen cap, don't try to click the links since it will not work :))

[image: GitHub - search for carousel3]

---

**Let's got to search `ImageCarousel` and we will find `ImageCarousel.kt`. Let's find `CarouselListener` in there**

[image: GitHub - search for ImageCarousel in ImageCarousel.kt]

We can see that when `CarouselListener` is set, it will immediately assign to `adapter?.listener` (Just ignore the "?" sign if you are not familiar with Kotlin)

**2nd question:** What is `adapter` here?

**Ans from the same file:**

```
private var adapter: FiniteCarouselAdapter? = null
```

**3rd question:** What is `FiniteCarouselAdapter`?

**Ans:** Its a `RecyclerView.Adapter`

```
open class FiniteCarouselAdapter(
...
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<FiniteCarouselAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
```

**Last question:** How is it related to `FiniteCarouselAdapter#listener`/`CarouselListener`/`adapter?.listener`?

When the `RecyclerView#Adapter` requires to call the `ViewHolder` method, it will call to `CarouselListener` methods instead.

**In FiniteCarouselAdapter:**

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
...
        // Init listeners
        listener?.onBindViewHolder(
            holder.binding,
            item,
            realItemPosition
        )
```

As `CarouselListener` is an interface, the method implementation will be defined in the `KotlinActivity` instead.

**In KotlinActivity:**

```
The above code in your question : )
```

Comment: So for me, I am guessing you are questioning how the library works.
If you are asking how a RecyclerView works, then definitely will be another answer.

Comment: I think the library contributors want users to have capability to control the RecyclerView view binding by their own. Otherwise, they can just accept a list of data, render them for you without your interception and tell you that this is a library restrictions/features if you ask for it.